# Congratulations to André Nicolas!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

Congratulations on reaching $200,000$ reputation! I think I speak for us all when I say that [your](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andre-nicolas) posts here are greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/

Comment: Hear, hear! Much appreciated indeed.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Can one make a wish for a different subject of the 200k commemoration painting? If not, I might stop posting at around 199k ... :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, search for "regex parse html" on Stackoverflow to understand the painting.

Comment: It won't help, @Hagen. Arturo's reputation, for instance, just keeps climbing, and he hasn't posted anything in over a year. ;-)

Comment: Thank you André for all of your contributions! You have posted **7152** answers as of now. Thousands of students (both the question askers, and the outside observers such as myself) have greatly benefited from your posts. Whenever I see a [number-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/212/number-theory) tagged question here, it makes me smile when I see an answer next to your name.

Comment: He's helped me many a time and generally beats me to answer!  Congrats!

Comment: @zyx Could you post a link?  I searched, but cannot find...

Comment: @anorton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: One of the users with the best didactical skills out there. Congrats and thanks for your work!

Comment: Is Andre really gone forever? I have wondered this for at least four years now. I wish I could've said at least a goodbye...

Comment: @qwr Same here...

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for all your help Andre!

Answer (score 10):

Congrats Andre. Lots of great posts.